# XCORE meets XTEXT

Tags: xtext, xbase, xcore

I have started creating the DSL using XTEXT and it is working really good. Today I found XCORE as another modeling approach that can be combined with XTEXT also. Can someone please explain what would be the use case of creating DSL with those two together.

I would be very thankful if someone can provided some documentation, examples or papers how to deal with them.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you be a bit more specific. do you want to define your metamodel with xcore and use that metamodel in xtext?

Comment: if yes there are some blogs around this e.g. https://blogs.itemis.com/en/using-xtext-with-xcore-and-gradle

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this post can help for the beginning of learning. The thing that I can't understand right now is what is the purpose of using metamodel for witing DSLs, since we still must define our grammar with XTEXT.

Comment: the point is defining the metamodel independently of the grammar